# Ubuntu Server won't start if no GPU is installed

Tags: ubuntu, boot, headless, graphic-card, cloud-init

I try to set my old PC as a headless Ubuntu Server.

When I first installed it with a GPU and then removed the GPU everything worked as excepted. My Motherboard (`Asus p8p67-m`) made one long and three short beeps at the start but then Ubuntu started.

Some days later I needed to configure RAID in the BIOS, so I installed another GPU (not the same I used while installing Linux) and then removed it again. Same beep noises but now Ubuntu won't start anymore.

Looking at the `kern.log` and `syslog.log` files I saw that nothing was written to it but at the `cloud-init.log` file there were some successful log entries (and I also could ping the server but no SSH). When I'm inserting the GPU again it works, if I remove it, it won't.

I did an update

```
apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

Could that be the problem?

Is there anyway to solve this issue, so I can remove the GPU again (as it cost some Watts)?

Running `Ubuntu 18.04 Serve without UI` with `ASUS P8P67-M` motherboard and a `NVidia GeForce GT 430`

Comment: "_I needed to configure RAID in the BIOS [...] now Ubuntu won't start anymore_". I would suggest that it is far more likely you've broken the expectations of either Ubuntu or Grub2 with respect to the disk layout. You should also check what the [beep code](https://superuser.com/a/783089/332907) means.

Comment: What makes you think it was the plugging and unplugging of the video card, and not the changing the configuration of your hard-disk, that causes the OS not to boot from the hard-disk?

Comment: Beep code was "No VGA" which makes sense to me. I thought it has to do with the VGA as when its absence it **wont** boot and when its plugged in ubuntu **will** boot. But I answered my own question below...

Answer (score 1):

As I run some tests thanks to the comments I figured out, that the problem is the fstab entry. If I comment out the fstab entry the system will boot without VGA installed. I find it quite strange, as it works when the VGA is installed.

After all I may mixed up FakeRAID and SoftwareRAID, but I'm not sure. I disabled RAID in BIOS, set my HDDs to AHCI and reinitiated the Software RAID with [this manual](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Software-RAID/) and now eveything works like a charm...

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratiulations on figuring the problem out by yourself. To make your answer more helpful to others who may be facing a similar issue, please edit your answer to include some details on the offending `fstab` entry, so that we may be able to figure out _why exactly_ that was the problem. As you pointed out yourself, it is quite strange after all ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't install it via any deployment method, your installation was manually. Since i didn't have to "re-install" - like Windows - since i'm on Linux, i'm not really familiar with the setup routine. IIRC there was an option for installing the X Server. But this is years ago. You might not have this option anymore.

So either you selected the X Server, to finish your installation/configuration, or you didn't even have the option to do so. The point is, your system is configured to have a desktop environment and your system will try to initialize it.

Maybe that is, where the problem lies. Try to deinstall it or deactivate it via systemd.

Usually the system won't have any problem, when it cant start X, the login manager or the desktop environment. But if there are kernel modules to be loaded, it might cause trouble.

Comment: I did install Ubuntu Server without UI (only the shell comes up after starting when I plug in a monitor)

Comment: Ok. Im pretty sure it has to do with GPU drivers a.k.a. kernel modules. Although it should be plug an play, i can imagine problems if they are configured but the hardware is missing. Being able to boot with the GPU tends in this direction. What GPUs were plugged? (You mentioned two)